# Как получить мета данные заказа WooCommerce API?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce, order

Предисловие:

Используется модуль Fields Factory:

При выборе кофе, к нему можно добавить сахар. Когда совершается заказ, эта добавка числится в meta заказа.

Вопрос: как получить эти meta в конструкции ниже?

Возможно, вы знаете решения, как зарегистрировать эти добавки, чтобы с ними можно было потом работать в API? В идеале хочу добиться того, чтобы эти добавки получали свой артикул.

Этот код написала в `functions.php`, чтобы собрать информацию о заказе при его совершении.

```
$items = $order->get_items();

$sku = array();
$product_qty = array();
$product_price = array();

foreach( $items as $key => $item){
    $product_qty[] = $item['qty'];
    $product_price[] = $item['line_total'];

    $item_id = $item['product_id'];
    $product_item = wc_get_product($item_id);
    $sku[] = $product_item->get_sku();
}
```

Comment: Что за манера - удалять предыдущие вопросы? Вы задаёте уже третий вопрос примерно на одну и ту же тему, а учитывая английский SO, уже четвёртый. Здесь база знаний, вопросы должны сохраняться.

Comment: Прошу прощения, дело в том, что показалось, что вопрос слишком не понятен. Да и реагировали на него типа "что тут непонятного?!". На зарубежном сайте и сказали удалять. Причем совершенно не оценив вопроса, минусуют и помечают как дубликат. Но на дворе 2018 год и многие функции устарели, их не используют, и они вызывают ошибку. А ссылаются на старые ответы, причем где вообще не php, а json. Поэтому сделала маленький вопрос, который полезен будет многим. Так как от модулей кастомные поля можно вытащить только из meta данных заказа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный код выводит мета данные товара. Пользовательские дополнения к товару не хранятся в мета заказа.

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// Цикл WC_Order_Item_Product, чтобы получить элементы заказа для версии WC 3+
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_product ){

    // Получить общие данные в массиве: 
    $item_product_data_array = $item_product->get_data();

    // Получить специальные метаданные в массиве: 
    $item_product_meta_data_array = $item_product->get_meta_data();

    // Получать только дополнительные метаданные (отформатированные в незащищенном массиве)
    $formatted_meta_data = $item->get_formatted_meta_data();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Заказ - это пост. Получить метаданные любого поста можно с помощью `get_post_meta()`. В данном случае:

```
$order_meta = get_post_meta( $order->get_id() );
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но вопрос всё-таки касается определённой конструкции. А так получаем весь массив. И выясняется проблема в том, что данных о модуля в них нет, но при совершении заказа он показывает добавки на странице.

Comment: Хотя смысла нет мета туда вписывать, так как это общая информация. А в ней по товарам разбито, соответственно и добавки относительно товара. Возможно тут нужно искать другие решения и регистрировать API кастомных полей и их значения. Как лучше поступить в такой ситуации, задать другой вопрос или этот изменить?

Comment: Дополнить вопрос деталями, поскольку никто не знает какеи у вас там мета. А вообще-то, считаю ответ исчерпыващим, потому что уж из массива выбрать нужные элементы - ну это как-то вы уж сами должны. Посмотрите содержимое этого массива, и выберите из него то, что нужно.

Comment: С одной стороны да, но в данном случае в контексте требуемых добавок оказывается, что их там вообще нет и быть не может. Сейчас думаю как корректно задать вопрос. Они же выводятся какими-то функциями и тут похоже, что их нужно регистрировать или вылавливать. У вас есть мысли на этот счёт?

Comment: Я ничего не знаю о ваших добавках. Если их нет, значит, в массиве нет таких элементов. Стройте код на основании этого. Или создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve